# SecKeyEncrypt returns errSecParam

Tags: ios, objective-c, commoncrypto

I am trying to encrypt some `NSData` using `SecKeyEncrypt` function. The problem is, it returns an error `-50`, which according to documentation is

> **errSecParam**
>   One or more parameters passed to the function are not valid.

The problem is, I can't find anything wrong with my function. Code is as follows

```
- (NSData *)encryptWithPrivateKey:(NSData *)plainData
{
    if (!privateKeyRef) {
        RBLog(@"No private key");
        return nil;
    }
    if (!plainData.length) {
        RBLog(@"Plain data empty");
        return nil;
    }

    size_t blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKeyRef); // 128
    NSMutableData *encryptedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:blockSize]; // using capacity of 1024 changes nothing
    size_t encryptedDataLen = blockSize;

    OSStatus status = SecKeyEncrypt(privateKeyRef,
                                    kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                                    (const uint8_t *)plainData.bytes,
                                    plainData.length,
                                    (uint8_t *)encryptedData.bytes,
                                    &encryptedDataLen);

    if (status != errSecSuccess) {
        RBLog(@"Could not encrypt, OS status %@", @(status));
    }
    return [NSData dataWithData:encryptedData];
}
```

The key is created using `SecKeyGeneratePair` which returns `errSecSuccess`. As you can see, I'm trying to encrypt the data with private key, not public one, so I have added

```
[privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanEncrypt];
```

to private key parameters upon generation, but that unfortunatelly didn't help.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution.

What I actually wanted to do was to have the data signed (that's why I was using private key to encrypt instead of public one), but it turns out `CommonCrypto` has a specific function just for that, so using

```
OSStatus status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKeyRef,
                                kPadding,
                                (const uint8_t *)plainText.bytes,
                                plainText.length,
                                (uint8_t *)encryptedData.bytes,
                                &encryptedDataLen);
```

solved the issue.